# Lazy-loading iframes as they scroll into view

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, dom, lazy

I'm working in a Tableau driven system, with large numbers of charts, I needed a way to reduce the strain of the initial load of our app. It's fairly simple, but wanted to ensure I accounted for every scenario, I don't generally utilize lazy loading.

Print isn't a priority.

jsfiddle: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/darcher/nkeryf4w/) (Tableau doesn't work within SO's [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) because of the iframes)

**Relevant Javascript**

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
    let canCall = true;
    return (...args) => {
      if (canCall) {
        fn.apply(null, args);
        canCall = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
          canCall = true;
        }, delay);
      }
    };
  };

  const setAttributes = (el, options) =>
    Object.keys(options).forEach(attr => el.setAttribute(attr, options[attr]));

  const w = window;
  const d = document;
  const b = d.body;
  const x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || b.clientWidth;
  const y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || b.clientHeight;

  /* unecessary, but to have same object format, e.g. readability */
  const win = Object.create(null);
  win.y = y;

  const frame = d.querySelectorAll("iframe");

  /** may be over doing it here... test results */
  const preloadPath = () =>
    frame.forEach(item => {
      const source = item.getAttribute("data-src");
      const preloadLink = d.createElement("link");
      const head = d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

      setAttributes(preloadLink, {
        rel: "preload",
        as: "document",
        type: "text/html",
        crossorigin: "anonymous",
        href: source
      });

      head.insertBefore(preloadLink, head.firstChild);
    });

  const loadFrame = () =>
    frame.forEach(item => {
      /* only run if not src is present */
      if (!item.src) {
        const source = item.getAttribute("data-src"); // path
        const parent = item.parentElement; // wrapper
        const frameRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect(); // wrapper dimensions

        if (
          w.pageYOffset + win.y >= frameRect.y && // if frame top exceeds page bottom
          frameRect.y + frameRect.height >= w.pageYOffset // if frame bottom exceeds page top
        ) {
          item.src = source; // set path
          item.removeAttribute("data-src"); // remove placeholder attr
        }
      }
    });

  /** load on docReady */
  d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", [preloadPath, loadFrame]);

  /** throttle on scroll */
  const t = throttle(loadFrame, 64);
  w.addEventListener("scroll", t);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `preloadPath`?

Comment: I was attempting to leverage [preloading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) although I don't believe it is of any benefit here, using javascript to inject into the DOM isn't early enough in the lifecycle of the page load... If it is beneficial, it's negligible.

Comment: If the purpose is to use `<link>` element is used to preload a resource, then `load` event of `<link>` should be used before `loadFrame()` is called. Presently `preloadPath` does not have direct relevance to the `<iframe>` elements, though can be utilized if `import` is used; see  [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824927/); [How to querySelector an element in an html import from a document that imports it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388003/).

Comment: That's actually a great point. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a bug in `throttle`. If `t` is called twice in quick succession, `loadFrame` will only be called in response to the first call to `t`. What you probably wanted in this case was to call `loadFrame` again 64 milliseconds after the first time it was called.

Comment: Intention is to execute _at most_ once every _n_ milliseconds.

Comment: @darcher I realise that, but you can still make sure it runs after every scroll event. On the first scroll event it should run the handler immediately. If the next scroll is within `n` milliseconds it should wait until the `n` milliseconds are up and then run the handler. If there are any more scroll events before it has run then they can be ignored, because the handler is going to run anyway.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I see your point, isn't that more of a debounce?

Comment: @darcher I don't know what the best name for it is. But the point is that if there are two scroll events less than 64 milliseconds apart (and no other scrolls), `loadFrame` will not be called after the second scroll, and the UI will remain in an inconsistent state. If you want to rename it as well then I'm not going to object.

Comment: I think `requestAnimationFrame()` may be a good option here, thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Feedback

The code in the jsFiddle Demo appears to function well (although it isn't the same as the code above- see the next section for an explanation). There is good usage of `const` for values that are not re-assigned and functional programming with arrow functions.

### Flaw with event listener setup

It appears that the fiddle has different code than appears here, but nonetheless, the code above contains the following line:

> ```
> d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", [preloadPath, loadFrame]);
> ```

The second argument appears to be an array. I haven't seen an array there used before and it doesn't appear to work. The [Parameters section of the MDN documentation for addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) reads:

> **`listener`**
>   The object which receives a notification (an object that implements the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. **This must be an object implementing the [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) interface, or a JavaScript [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)**. See [The event listener callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback) for details on the callback itself.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)</sup>

If you did need to have both functions run when that event occurs, you would either need to have a single callback function that calls both or call `addEventListener` once for each function. It appears that in the fiddle `preloadPath` has been removed...

### Suggestions

#### Variable naming

The variable name `frame` sounds singular, yet it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which would typically contain multiple DOM elements.

> ```
> const frame = d.querySelectorAll("iframe");
> ```

Thus a more appropriate name would be `frames`. That way when statements like `frames.forEach()` is read, it implies that a function is invoked for each of the frames.

#### The `setAttributes()` function

Correct me if I am wrong but this function appears to do the same thing that [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). I was able to replace calls to that function with calls to `Object.assign()` and still saw the attributes set as expected in Opera and Chrome.

#### Arrow functions with empty argument lists

You don't have to do this, but `_` could be used instead of empty parentheses for arrow functions with no named arguments. Refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41085189/1575353) and its answers for more context.

#### timeout in function returned by `throttle()`

While it would only save a couple lines, the arrow function passed to `setTimeout()` in the function returned by `throttle()` could be simplified to remove the curly braces. While this would mean that `true` would be returned, it doesn't affect anything.

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let canCall = true;
  return (...args) => {
    if (canCall) {
      fn.apply(null, args);
      canCall = false;
      setTimeout(_ => canCall = true, delay);
    }
  };
};
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)</sub>

Comment: yeah actually in the version I'm using it has a `const readyInit = (() => {preloadPath();loadFrame();});` function I call on DOMReady. This was actually due to me showing a collage "I wish we could" and must have overlooked it when posting a copy+paste; good eye. I was not aware of the Lambda expression for empty ()! All valid and good points, thanks for your input! I'll update the OP to reflect changes when I get a moment.

Comment: Cool; Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114). You could post a follow up question with update code...

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code based on the suggestions in comments and answers.

shout out to [Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/s%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%8D-on%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%8C%E1%B4%80) for his suggestions in the accepted answer and [David Knipe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34881/david-knipe) for suggestions on the `throttle` function.

```
const w = window;
const d = document;

let timeout;
const throttle = (fn, ...args) => (
  timeout && w.cancelAnimationFrame(timeout),
  timeout = w.requestAnimationFrame(_ => fn(...args)));

const loadFrame = _ => 
    d.querySelectorAll("iframe").forEach(frame => {
    if (frame.src) return
    const frameRect = frame.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    (w.pageYOffset + d.documentElement.clientHeight >= frameRect.y
      && frameRect.y + frameRect.height >= w.pageYOffset)
      && frame.setAttribute('src', frame.getAttribute("data-src"))
              .removeAttribute("data-src")});

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadFrame, false);
w.addEventListener("scroll", _ => throttle(loadFrame), false);
```